# Functions for this screen width still works for different screen width

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make functions depends on screen sizes:

```
var Scroll = function(ele) {
    if (ele.width() <= 991) {
        $("header").css('background', '#001128 none repeat scroll 0 0');
        $('.banner-area').css('margin-top', '200px');
        $(document).scroll(function() { console.log('less than 992'); });
    }

    if (ele.width() >= 992) {
        $("header").css('background', 'unset');
        $('.banner-area').css('margin-top', '0px');
        var scroll_pos = 0;
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_pos > 485) {
                $("header").css('background', '#001128 none repeat scroll 0 0');
            } else {
                console.log('more than 991');
                $("header").css('background', 'unset');
            }
        });
    }
}

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    Scroll($('body'));
});

Scroll($('body'));
```

This is actually a working code, but when i use the `Inspect Element` - `Toggle device toolbar` to check if its working with this size it goes like this:

If onload the width 992px or more:

When I scroll less than 485 then the console will show `more than 991` and the `header` will change the `background` to `unset` but when I change the size to less than 992px using `Inspect Element` - `Toggle device toolbar`, when I try to scroll the console will show `less than 992` and also show `more than 991` and  `header` will stil change its `background` to `unset` and vice versa.

Note: If page is reloaded there is no problem, just when the screen width size is resized using `Inspect Element` - `Toggle device toolbar`

Comment: You have attached the function to the window resize event. Changing body width is not firing the window resize

Comment: You attach `Scroll` to window resize, then, within that scroll, you attach *another* event on `$(document).scroll`.  So each time you resize, you get a 2nd event that fires when you scroll.  When you then resize the window a 2nd time you now have 2 scroll events, 3rd time, 3 scroll events etc.   The previous document scrolls are still firing for when the width was different.

Comment: @freedomn-m how can i prevent that from firing?

Comment: You can use jQuery's .off('scroll') or JS's addEventListener and removeEventListener to prevent this behavior.

Comment: I recommend adding `$(document).scroll` in the doc.ready and then check the `$(body).width` inside the doc.scroll handler.  Then it will act accordingly no matter what the width.  If you're worried about it taking too long, then `debounce` the scroll event.

Comment: can you guys provide solutions for me? I kinda not understand it that much, I also tried `debounce` but it isnt working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that the document.scroll handler is initialised each time the window resizes, so on the 2nd resize you get 2 scroll handlers, each for the size it was a the time of the resize.

Instead, add the document.scroll during document.ready and check the size within that handler:

```js
var scroll = function(ele) {
  if (ele.width() < 992) {
    $("header").css('background', '#001128 none repeat scroll 0 0');
    $('.banner-area').css('margin-top', '200px');
  } else  {
    $("header").css('background', 'unset');
    $('.banner-area').css('margin-top', '0px');
  }
};

$(document).scroll(function() {
  if (ele.width() < 992) {
    console.log('less than 992');
  } else {
    console.log('more than 991');
    var scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_pos > 485) {
      $("header").css('background', '#001128 none repeat scroll 0 0');
    } else {
      $("header").css('background', 'unset');
    }
  }
});


$(window).on('resize', function() {
  scroll($('body'));
});

scroll($('body'));
```